# Error connecting to db with jboss tools / hibernate configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jboss, postgis

I'm attempting to use jboss tools hibernate code generation to generate DAOs and hibernate mappings for tables in my postgresql db.  I have set-up my hibernate configuration but when I try to connect I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.<clinit>(StandardBasicTypes.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect.registerTypesAndFunctions(PostgisDialect.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect.<init>(PostgisDialect.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.constructDialect(DialectFactory.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2155)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration$6.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.getSettings(ConsoleConfiguration.java:428)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.readDatabaseSchema(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I've looked inside StandardBasicTypes at line 54, which reads `public static final BooleanType BOOLEAN = BooleanType.INSTANCE;` and I've followed the field BooleanType.INSTANCE that does exist in class BooleanType.

I'm using hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar, hibernate-spatial-4.0-M1.jar, and in my hibernate configuration, "Hibernate Version" is "4.0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with my hibernate configuration, specifically the driver and dialect.  Originally, I had

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgis.DriverWrapper</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect</property>
```

And I was receiving the error stack trace in the question above.  I changed these properties to

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
```

And was able to connect to the db through hibernate tools.  If anyone cares, I created a JIRA [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HBX-1221) to track the issue should anyone want to be able to use hibernate tools with geospatial objects.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you dont have two hibernate version on your classpath

Comment: I don't believe multiple versions of the hibernate jars are on the classpath but I'm not 100%.  How would I check without a doubt if this is the case?

Comment: if you are on eclipse right click on project - Properties - JavaBuild Path - Libraries.

Comment: The only hibernate jars listed in libraries are hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1, hibernate-core-4.1.8, hibernate-jpa-2.0, hibernate-spatial-4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently all of your Hibernate jars and it's configuration in the editor need to match. Geofflittle's answer is spot on only if you make sure that your hibernate-spatial + hibernate-core + hibernate version selection in the editor drop-down are all at the same version.